# Truncate date while using the Now() function

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to know how to truncate a date when using the `Now()` function to avoid having hours seconds and minutes.  Effectively I would would like to show only `dd/mmm/yyyy`.

My current code which is:

```
[Expected start date] = Now()
```

is returning in the field box:

13/04/2014 22:24:10

When i wish it would only return

13/04/2014

I imagine this may be simple for most but I am a beginner.

Comment: What is [Expected start date]? Is it a label or textbox?

Comment: Does `[Expected start date] = Date()` give you what you want?

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Similar to the today's date function in Excel! grazie Hans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Format. You really don't want to set the Expected start date field to a date, but instead a string.

```
Format(Now(),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```